# Reading very large CSV and JSON files

Tags: c#, json, csv, memory

I am currently programming a "search engine" in C# for a game, from which i get very large (3GB and more!) .csv and .json(l) files, I need to parse them, but it takes up very large amounts of RAM... what are good ways to parse them (I need all the data for transfering it into a DB)?

example csv:

```
id,station_id,commodity_id,supply,buy_price,sell_price,demand,collected_at
1,1,5,0,0,315,532,1486247405
2,1,6,0,0,6795,38,1486247405
3,1,7,0,0,527,318,1486247405
```

Unfortunatly no json example, but it is an array of OBJs which hold the data.

Comment: Can you provide short samples of `csv` and `json` files? And also some code that you have already.

Comment: @http://stackoverflow.com/users/283606/aleksandr-ivanov first line of the csv is the order (according to the documentation this order might change!) and the other lines are said data:

Comment: id,station_id,commodity_id,supply,buy_price,sell_price,demand,collected_at
1,1,5,0,0,315,532,1486247405
2,1,6,0,0,6795,38,1486247405
3,1,7,0,0,527,318,1486247405

Comment: You need to use a stream-based API where you read a single line or token, parse it, then discard it and read the next. For example the JSON.NET [`JsonTextReader`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonTextReader.htm).

Comment: For csv you can just use `StreamReader.ReadLine` and then parse it yourself.

Comment: @Dour High Arch thanks, that solves the json problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used *[Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser(v=vs.110).aspx)* and it was fast enough for a 2 GB .CSV file.

```
using (TextFieldParser sr = new TextFieldParser(datapath)
        {
            Delimiters = new string[1] { "," },
            HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = true;
        })
{
     string[] values = sr.ReadFields();
     while (values != null)
     {
      // ....
      values = sr.ReadFields();
     }
}
```

Hope it helps.